# Is this MergeSort?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, merge, mergesort

i tried to code MergeSort. But my Code looks very different than famous implementations of MergeSort. So i'd like to know, if my implementation is correct. My Algorithm takes two int arrays (each is sorted) and puts them into a sorted big array. And whats the asymptotic complexity of my algorithm? Thank you very much!!

```
public static int[] myMergeSort(int[] array, int[] array2) {
    int[] giveback = new int[array.length + array2.length];
    int i = 0; 
    int j = 0; 

    for (int x = 0; x < giveback.length; x++) {
        if (array[i] >= array2[j]){
            giveback[x] = array2[j];
            j++;
        } else {
            giveback[x] = array[i];
            i++;
        }

        if (i == array.length) {
            x++;
            for (int c = j; c < array2.length; c++) {
                giveback[x] = array2[c];
                x++;    
            }
            return giveback;
        }

        if (j == array2.length) {
            x++;
            for (int b = i; b < array.length; b++){
                giveback[x] = array[b];
                x++;
            }
            return giveback;
        }
    }

    return giveback;
}
```

Comment: Mergesort is generally understood to take a single, unsorted array as input, so the problem you are solving is considerably simpler.

Comment: I see the merge.  I don't see the sort.

Comment: This is just part of merg sort

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is a merge (not a merge sort) that merges two already sorted arrays. Time complexity is O(n), where n is the sum of the number of elements in array + number of elements in array2.